# Parsing yaml python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

There is a file in yaml markup

```
 a:
  b:x
  test2
  test
  test3
```

How to use python (2.7.x) and PyYAML get x?

Answer (score 2):

You can't! The YAML you posted results in a dict containing just a single key, `a` which maps to the value `"b:x test2 test test3"` - you can easily test that by [pasting your YAML here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/).

The reason for this is that you cannot mix `key: value` pairs and keyless items (like there would be in an array).

However, let's assume that you have proper YAML that contains an object `a` containing another object that maps `b` to `x`. For example this:

```
a:
    b: x
    c: test2
    d: test
    e: test3
```

In this case you'd use `foo['a']['b']` to access `x` with `foo` being the object returned by your YAML parser.

The python code to get `foo` could look like this:

```
import yaml
with open('yourfile.yaml') as f:
    foo = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

I'm using `safe_load` since you most likely do not intend to create arbitrary Python objects from your YAML document and thus you want to use a function that cannot open a security hole if ever passed a malicious YAML document.